# Leave a tenant in azure portal without login into its

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azureportal, azure-entra-id

I want to leave an azure tenant I don't work with long time already (I didn't touch it more than 5 years), but this tenant is stored in my tenants list and periodically when I work with azure this tenant is chosed as first auth option despite I use other ones (I have 3+ more) almost each day.

When I click `leave` button in "manage tenant" form (Microsoft Entra ID), the  portal first tries to login me into this account which I don't have access to, so it fails.

Does anyone have any ideas how to leave a tenant without login into its?

**UPDATE1:**
Screenshot:
[image]

**UPDATE2:**
[image]

Comment: You need to login at least **once** that takes you to _https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations_ page where you can click [`Leave`](https://i.imgur.com/48UyC0J.png) button to [leave](https://i.imgur.com/i0ZAK4S.png) the tenant. Alternatively, you can contact the administrator of that tenant to remove your user account from that tenant. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1330326/how-can-i-remove-a-tenant-that-i-no-longer-have-ac

Comment: sounds like I already "removed" there. When I try to login (for leaving, it says: `Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.`. Something else can be done here?

Comment: Could you include the screenshot of the page where you got error? May be the account is locked due to multiple incorrect password attempts.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/access-management/account-blocked-error-when-sign-in

Comment: @Sridevi, done. I would say it's expected to be locked since I don't work with this company (owner of the tenant) more than 5 years..

Comment: Could you include `Settings` page of your Azure Portal, highlighting the tenant you want to leave like [this](https://i.imgur.com/9izPWZg.png)?

Comment: not sure, do you mean page like in UPDATE2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256993/discussion-between-sridevi-and-unnamed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have below list of **directories** that are visible in the Azure Portal of my user account:

[image]

You can login to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations with your account and find all **organizations** that you are part of with <kbd>**Leave**</kbd> button at the end:

[image]

After clicking on <kbd>**Leave**</kbd> button, it will take you to below page with **confirmation** prompt to leave tenant:

[image]

When I clicked on <kbd>**Leave**</kbd> button again in above prompt, I got this screen saying *"You've left tenant"*:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal after 30 minutes where *Contoso* tenant is not visible anymore in directories page like this:

[image]

> If your account is locked out, you need to contact the **administrator** of that tenant who can perform steps mentioned in this **[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/access-management/account-blocked-error-when-sign-in)** to resolve it.

Alternatively, you can change **Startup directory** setting on your Azure Portal to avoid authenticating to tenant that you don't have access to.

[image]

Here, you can select the **directory** to which you want to login by **default** whenever you sign in and click on <kbd>**Apply**</kbd> button:

[image]

**Reference:**
[How can I remove a tenant that I no longer have access to - Microsoft Q&A by **Sandeep G-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1330326/how-can-i-remove-a-tenant-that-i-no-longer-have-ac)